# How to transport information from one form to another using dto, C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, dto

I'm having trouble transporting information from one form to another, is to make a single save, but the information is distributed in 2 forms and I have to do it using dto. I know that for this I have to send the data that I want by the form builder method, as you can see in the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSKVD.png) below:

```cs
public FrmModalFornecedor(int providerId, int providerDoc)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CbxListarFornecedor();
    providerDoc = Convert.ToInt32(txtDoc.Text);
    providerId = Convert.ToInt32(((Provider)cbxFornecedor.SelectedItem).ProviderId);
}
```

But now my questions are:

1. How to make these variables take their respective text box and combo box values?
2. How to make the next form have access to this data?

Comment: Looks like a simple typo, you probably meant to assign this.providerDoc instead of the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional properties in the second form and you can pass the values from first form to second form.

Hope this gives some ideas for you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.MyName = "Pass my name here";
    frm.Show();
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string MyName { get; set }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```